# Solspace Freeform Pro no field types available

Tags: php, solspace-freeform, fieldtype, solspace

I recently bought freeform PRO(version 4.0.11) and upgraded my freeform(version 4.0.8) using the Solspace update method.

When I navigate to the module page and select the tab **field types** the page shows the following message.

```
No field types available.
What, you deleted all of the default ones, too? O_o
```

It also throws some PHP error's.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: glob() [function.glob]: Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters
Filename: libraries/Freeform_fields.php
Line Number: 300

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: libraries/Freeform_fields.php
Line Number: 302
```

When I open the freeform_fields.php file from the libraries folder and navigate to line 300 I see the following piece of code.

```
    // -------------------------------------
    //  default fields
    // -------------------------------------

    $default_fields = glob(
        $this->default_path . 'freeform_ft.{' .
            implode(',', $this->data->defaults['default_fields']) . '}.php',
        GLOB_BRACE
    );
```

If I open the **default_fields** folder it shows a lot of freeform_ft_FIELDTYPENAME.php files.

Whats wrong and how can I fix it without removing/uninstalling the whole module and install it again? I want to keep my submissions.

Comment: If you go to Tools->Data->SQL manager and select manage tables, is there a table called exp_freeform_fieldtypes?
If there is, is there any data in it?

Comment: Yes there is a table called exp_freeform_fieldtypes and the table is filled with data.

Comment: If you want to email me a CP login and FT access I'd be happy to take a look under the hood. jim dot wyse at solspace.com

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query to build the fieldtypes table.
(as always, make sure you have backups before doing anything like this!)

Another thing to try is to delete your FreeForm folders in third_party and themes and upload them fresh. Often people try to just overwrite existing folders with the upgrade and strange things can happen.  THis will not uninstall the module, so your data should be safe.  It just makes sure the right files are in the right place.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `exp_freeform_fieldtypes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_fieldtypes` (
  `fieldtype_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldtype_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settings` text,
  `default_field` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `version` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fieldtype_id`),
  KEY `fieldtype_name` (`fieldtype_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `exp_freeform_fieldtypes`
--

INSERT INTO `exp_freeform_fieldtypes` (`fieldtype_id`, `fieldtype_name`, `settings`, `default_field`, `version`) VALUES
(1, 'checkbox', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(2, 'checkbox_group', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(3, 'country_select', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(4, 'file_upload', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(5, 'hidden', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(6, 'mailinglist', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(7, 'multiselect', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(14, 'province_select', '[]', 'n', '4.0.10'),
(9, 'radio', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(10, 'select', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(11, 'state_select', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(12, 'text', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1'),
(13, 'textarea', '[]', 'n', '4.0.0.b1');
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it didn't work. I think the problem is the first PHP error. Windows only allows you to use a maximum of 260 characters in your file path. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath I thought maybe it possible to use the symlink() method of PHP to create a symbolic link for the var $this->default_path but that throws another PHP error.

Comment: Gotta love IIS servers.  Not sure what to tell you at this point. This is looking like a server issue, not an issue with FreeForm.  Chances are you may run into this with other addons as well.  I'll look around and see what I can find out.

Comment: I've limited my file path to less then 260 characters and the PHP error's dissapear but the problem related to **default_fields** is still there.

Comment: Can I get a Super Admin login to the site?

Comment: I can't give you the credentials of the production environment. I've tried to reproduce the situation in the test-environment(unix) but that didn't work the field types will load succesfully. Also I get this problem in my development environment and you can't reach that. Maybe you could reproduce the situation I'm running WAMPP webserver on Windows 7 x64

Comment: At least we have narrowed it down to a difference in servers.  I currently don't have WAMP installed or have access to a windows server. Just to be clear your production server is windows, and the issue happens there, but not on a linux server?

Comment: Just to be clear.
Development Environment = Windows(7 64x) | Testing Environment = UNIX | Production Evironment is UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Wyse

Could you find out why the following piece of code doesn't work on my Windows machine? It also outputs an empty array. The vars $this->default_path and $this->data->defaults['default_fields'] are filled with data. Maybe it could be related to the **glob** method.

**File:** Freeform_fields.php

**Line:** 296

```
    $default_fields = glob(
        $this->default_path . 'freeform_ft.{' .
            implode(',', $this->data->defaults['default_fields']) . '}.php',
        GLOB_BRACE
    );
```

I temporarly fixed it by creating the **$default_fields** array and pushed the file paths in there with the **array_push** method(not fully dnynamic like the code posted above).

```
    //Create an array
    $default_fields = array();

    //Foreach default field in default fields
    foreach($this->data->defaults['default_fields'] as $default_field)
    {
        //Push file path to default fields array
        array_push($default_fields, '../system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/default_fields/freeform_ft.'.$default_field.'.php');
    }
```

Comment: How deeply nested on the server is your install folder? I was going to suggest that we change the glob function to something else, but I am thinking that's not the issue and rather its too many folders deep with too long names.

Comment: Starting from my C: drive it's five folders deep then you will reach the related expressionengine project(root folder of the website).