# FreeForm 4.1.3 is not showing any field types and I'm unable to create any fields or forms

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm using the free version of FreeForm 4.1.3 and Exp Eng v2.7.3 - Build Date: 20131210. I found a similar question here on StackExchange...
[Solspace Freeform Pro no field types available](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/solspace-freeform-pro-no-field-types-available)

I'm unable to create any fields and the default ones aren't there. I'm also unable to create any forms. When I do a submit for creating a new form I'm just sent back to the control panel home page. The page for creating new fields shows the following php warnings...

Normally I never see any problems with FreeForm. The only thing different here that I can think of is that the Exp Eng system directory is above the web root in my configuration.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: libraries/Freeform_fields.php
Line Number: 249

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Freeform_fields.php
Line Number: 254

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: freeform/mcp.freeform.php
Line Number: 3128
```

Comment: Do you see the same message as described in http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/solspace-freeform-pro-no-field-types-available? i.e. "*No field types available.
What, you deleted all of the default ones, too? O_o*"

Comment: Have you tried running the query suggested in http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/solspace-freeform-pro-no-field-types-available?

Comment: No, I don't see that message listed in the other post. I haven't run the query since I'm using EngineHosting and it's unlikely the site is running on a Windows server. I also wanted more details before running that type of query. Is running the query to build the table what you suggest?

Comment: This ever get resolved? Have same issue.