# Freeform Pro upgrade failing

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm mid upgrade of an EE 1.6.7 install with Freeform Pro 2.7.2. I have completed upgrading the site to 2.8.1( I know 2.9.x exists...), and now when I try to update Freeform to 4.1.8, nothing is happening.

I've copied in the new folders, gone into the Add-Ons / Module screen and ran the "Update Modules" function. Freeform then shows an updated version number to 4.1.8. Then when I go into Freeform itself, the tool works, but I have no forms showing, nor any fields. When I go into utilities, it gives me the option of migrating old collections, which I initiate, only it stalls out at "Migrating 0/9128.

*UPDATE

I followed the direction given in this post: [Solspace Freeform Pro no field types available](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/solspace-freeform-pro-no-field-types-available) for adding in the missing freeform fields table, which fixed that portion, along with freeform now showing all of my previous fields from before the upgrade, so that's working now.The only thing left is the migration of collections are still failing and the forms tab is still blank... even though there should be forms.

In looking further into the DB, which is getting in over my head, the Freeform upgrade renamed the original table exp_freeform_entries, to exp_freeform_entries_legacy, then created a new exp_freeform_entries_1, but seems to never have actually converted any of the data or columns from _legacy into _1. Is there a way to run a SQL query to do that? Like I said, it's over my head at this point...

[image: EE Upgraded, FreeForm 4 files added, control panel now shows FF 2 and the upgrade link]
[image: FreeForm 4 upgrade successfully completed]
[image: No forms exist after upgrade]
[image: No fields exist after upgrade]
[image: Utilities shows migration option]
[image: Migration stalls and never completes]

Answer (score 2):

This has been mentioned a number of times by a number of developers, but it's worth mentioning here again, as it's important:

> ★ 
>   When upgrading from EE1 to EE2, **always upgrade add-ons first, as far as possible, while still on EE1**, *then* upgrade to EE2. 
>   ★
>
> (*Then, if some add-ons have further EE2 versions, continue and complete updating the add-ons once on EE2.*)

Freeform 2.x (which is more than 5 years old as of this writing) is an EE1-only add-on, with a database schema that Freeform 4.x, which is EE2-only, cannot read. The best method is to upgrade Freeform 2.x to 3.1.5 (the last version for EE1) while still on EE1, then upgrade EE2.

Then, complete the update Freeform to version 4.x.

---

The other option is to start fresh with Freeform 4.x on your now EE2 setup.

Comment: It would be super helpful to be able to access these previous versions for download.

Comment: You can always email us at support@solspace.com to access older versions :)